# Let $v_p(n)$ denotes the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$. Evaluate $v_3(2^{3^n}+1)$. Also Find the generalization of the problem.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, exponentiation

Let $v_p(n)$ denotes the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$. Calculate $v_3(2^{{3}^{n}}+1)$. Is there any generalization of it?

My try : Answer is $v_3(2^{3^n}+1)=n+1$.
I tried to prove it by induction. For $n=1$ it is trivial. For $n=k$ and $n=k+1$ I have also proved by induction and got the answer as $n+1$. But I got stuck when I was told to find the generalization of the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Find *the* [ultimate] generalization" is impossible. At best *some* generalization ;-).

Comment: Perhaps this is interesting for you: https://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf I discussed this (however as an amateur in NT) to wide generalization.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $\ p\ $ is *any* prime, what is the largest power of $\ p\ $ that divides
$$
(p-1)^{p^n}+1\ ?
$$

Comment: (+1) any *odd* prime ;-)

Comment: @AnneBauval - what about the "oddest" prime? :-)